# how can I leverage native Windows ODBC drivers remotely via fabric?

Tags: python, odbc, cygwin, fabric

I can connect to a system DSN running [my cygwin compatible fork](https://bitbucket.org/yekibud/pypyodbc) of [pypyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) locally on Windows 7, but when I try to run the same script via SSH/fabric, I get a permission error:

```
[192.168.x.x] out:     conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=xxx;PWD=xxx')
[192.168.x.x] out:   File "/home/tschmidt/.virtualenvs/dashboard/src/pypyodbc/pypyodbc.py", line 2081, in __init__
[192.168.x.x] out:     self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)
[192.168.x.x] out:   File "/home/tschmidt/.virtualenvs/dashboard/src/pypyodbc/pypyodbc.py", line 2129, in connect
[192.168.x.x] out:     validate(ret, SQL_HANDLE_DBC, self.dbc_h)
[192.168.x.x] out:   File "/home/tschmidt/.virtualenvs/dashboard/src/pypyodbc/pypyodbc.py", line 989, in validate
[192.168.x.x] out:     ctrl_err(handle_type, handle, ret)
[192.168.x.x] out:   File "/home/tschmidt/.virtualenvs/dashboard/src/pypyodbc/pypyodbc.py", line 974, in ctrl_err
[192.168.x.x] out:     raise Error(state,err_text)
[192.168.x.x] out: pypyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft]
    [ODBC Microsoft   Access Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot 
    open the file '(unknown)'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, 
    or you need permission to view its data.")
```

Using MDBTools is not an option as I need to make connections to other databases that only have Windows drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by switching to Windows XP.  Would still like to know what the cause of the problem was, though.  New permissions in Windows 7 I assume.